# How to adjust data to remove influence of one or more features

Tags: predictive-models, feature-selection, adjustment

For my first real data science project I would like to develop a model which better reflects review quality than "useful" votes. I am working with Yelp's latest Academic data set but this thinking could apply to review data sets from other entities such as Amazon.

Exploratory analysis suggests at least 3 factors that impact useful votes in a way that does not reflect review quality:

1. Timing: If a review is one of the first few, it will (on average) garner more useful votes than if it had been posted as the 100th review.
2. Friends: If a reviewer has many friends or fans, he/she will (on average) get more useful votes than if there were zero or few friends/fans.
3. User longevity/trustworthiness: This one is specific to Yelp - If a user is new to the system (< 5 reviews), most reviews will be filtered into the "not recommended" bucket most (or all) of the time until the reviewer is more established. While no reviews in the data set are from this bucket, some of them have been in the filtered review bucket for much of the time, thus not having had as much opportunity to garner usefulness votes.

Let's focus on the timing factor, as it is a common issue with all review systems, and is simpler. So for this question, assume:

- You have 20 features (which are unlikely to be totally independent from each other)
- One feature is "timing" which is a number. 1 means it was earliest review, 2 means 2nd earliest, etc.
- "usefulness" is the dependent variable

I understand that there are some methods to determine the relative weighting of how much each variable contributes, or the ordering of which variable contributes the most, which 2nd most, etc.

My question is:

How do I back out the influence of this "timing" variable on "usefulness" votes? Stated another way:

How can I algorithmically adjust the raw data (the number of useful votes) such that when I do an analysis of the contribution of each variable to the "usefulness" score, the "timing" variable will contribute zero?

Intuitively, this would mean that reviews with a low timing number would have usefulness adjusted down, while reviews with a high timing number will have usefulness adjusted up. Once data is adjusted this way, a model can be trained on the adjusted data that will reflect review quality independent of the timing factor.

I am hoping the answer will include a high level description of the steps one must take to achieve this, including type of factor analysis to be used, if any.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you would

a) use a statistical model to predict usefulness from timing alone->  predicted_usefulness(timing) 
b) calculate prediction_error using this model: this is the usefulness taking out what can be predicted by timing alone.
c)  use a model to predict this residual=[usefulness votes - predicted_usefulness(timing)] with the remaining variables.

ps the problem you will probably run into is if there are some correlations between the independent variables. eg assume people who drink  also tend to smoke, and you are predicting health problems. then first predicting health effects from drinking will also take away some smoking associated effect ( imagine if all your drinkers were smokers). there is nothing you can really do about this in a non experimental setting [ you need to basically get equal numbers of your different groups]

Comment: Yes - clearly the variables are not completely independent from each other, which is what makes this seem difficult. Interpolation would be possible if you had infinite computing power - try adjusting the "usefulness" dependent variable in different ways and keep trying new values for it until the amount of contribution from the "timing" variable came close to zero. But I imagine this would be too costly. Are you saying there's a method to do this that is more efficient? If so, please elaborate.

Comment: I have expanded my answer: the way you remove timing is by predicting usefulness from timing with whatever model you wish, and subtracting this prediction from usefulness. Now when you build a model to predict this residual timing will have no effect (it has already been taken out)